# What are the approaches to ensure bandwidth to a remote location?

Tags: file-transfer

Our file transfers have always been within our own network and it's been relatively easy to control QOS where we own the network equipment.

But now, we are going to move one of our systems where we need to send files to up to a remote data center in another country. Given that the connection from our DC to the remote DC is going to go through several ISPs, backbones and last miles, how are we to ensure that we will get a guaranteed throughput?

The size of data is actually not that big at all (just about 500MBs that need to be transferred within 30 minutes) but the only part that I am comfortable guaranteeing right now is the last mile between my DC and my ISP. After that, as far as I know, it's up to various networks that the data travels through and I'd like to get advice on how to guaranteed these portions of the transfer.

Wong

Comment: `how are we to ensure that we will get a guaranteed throughput?` - You can't unless you own, operate or lease the connection from end to end. You have no control over the network in between the two systems.

Comment: The part that you're "comfortable guaranteeing" is the part most likely to be a problem!